# Modifying a pointer to an array in a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with passing an array to a function and then modifying it. For example:

```
void foo(int ** a) {
  int * b = new int[3]
  //Initialize b, i.e b = {3, 2, 1}
  a = &b;
  //*a = {3, 2, 1}
}

int * c = new int[3]
//Initialize c; c = {1, 2, 3}
foo(&c);
// c is still {1, 2, 3}. Why?
```

I'm not really sure why `c` doesn't point to the same array as `b`.

Comment: `*a = b;` Should work. Though I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Arunmu Yea that works, thanks.

Comment: @MarkoStojanovic Your question is little similar to the behavior explained in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776010/pass-by-reference-and-value-with-pointers) question so it will also help you understand your problem :)

Comment: @ItbanSaeed Yes, I was looking for exactly that, but didn't find it myself. I guess I didn't know how to form the statement properly when googling.

Comment: its no problem, there is no rocket science in googling. You might have not reached the link from the results.. I just thought about making your issue little more clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` has type `int**` and it's passed by value, so modifying it does not modify `c`.

To modify it, you have to do this:

```
  *a = b;
```

By doing this, you assign the address of `b` to the variable pointed by `*a` (which corresponds to `c`), so they will point to the same array.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that `c`'s location is passed by value, so I thought `*a = b` and `a = &b` would be equivalent.