# pointer problems with function calls

Tags: c++

I’m working on a beginner(!) exercise.

I am comfortable passing basic variables and also using &variable parameters so I can make changes to the variable that are not destroyed when returning.  But am still learning pointers.  I am working on the basic Mutant Bunny exercise (linked list practice).

In it I create a linked list by declaring Class Bunny.  I set it up as you expect with a data section and a ‘next’ pointer for set up the linkage.

```
struct Bunny {
    string name;
    int age;
    // more variables here
    Bunny* next;
};
```

Everything works great when I call function to do things like create Bunnies using the function:

```
Bunny* add_node ( Bunny* in_root ){}
```

This sets up the node and returns it just like I want.   I can also do things like call a function to modify the Bunny class like aging the bunnies.

```
void advanceAge ( Bunny* in_root ){}
```

I pass in the head and then I can modify the bunnies in the called function and it stays modified even when it goes back to main.  For example I can use:

```
in_root->age ++;
```

in the called function and when I return to ‘main’ it is still changed.  Basically I can use -> in any called function and it makes the change permanently.  I think because the pointer is dereferenced(?) by the -> but still getting my head around it...

So far so good.

The problem comes up when I want call a function to delete the list.  (Nuclear option… no more bunnies)

I can delete all the nodes in the called function… but it does not change the Bunny in ‘main’.  For example… this does not permanently remove the node.

```
void DeathCheck(Bunny* in_root){
    Bunny* prev_ptr;
    prev_ptr = in_root;
    if (prev_ptr == NULL){
        cout << "No list to check age." << endl; return;
    } else {        
prev_ptr = NULL;   // <- what could I code to have this stick?      return;} 
// rest of DeathCheck
```

I’m curious if there is a way to set the node to NULL in the called function and have it stick?

Comment: You need to provide more details. How exactly add_node() works. And where exactly, and how, is the entire list of bunnies is stored. There's a reasonable chance that you may not be doing what you think you're doing in add_node().

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing `in_root` by value, there's no way for it to modify the caller's variable. You could pass it by reference.

```
void DeathCheck(Bunny* &in_root) {
    Bunny *prev_ptr = in_root;
    ...
    in_root = nullptr;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in `DeathCheck(Bunny* in_root)`, there is no way that `in_root` can be changed, only the object it is pointing to can be changed. (See [pass by reference and value with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776010/pass-by-reference-and-value-with-pointers)). Based on this, you need to change the parameter to pass-by reference, eg by changing the signature of your function to this:

```
DeathCheck(Bunny* &in_root) 
{
    //...
}
```

This passes the `Bunny` by reference, meaning that it can now be reassigned to without a copy.